# JFrame sometimes not appearing at all?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I currently have a JFrame created by NetBeans. Most of the time, when I run the program it works completely fine -- the GUI appears, the components are correct, the values I set are correct, etc.

Every so often, however, the GUI will fail to appear. Just... Doesn't appear. There's just no frame that appears. What's worse is that Java still returns true for JFrameInstance.isVisible() and forces me to manually kill the program. In other words, the program doesn't stop. I have yet to find an answer for this.

My code, sans the excess setup code:

```
public class Setup extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  /** Creates new form Setup */
  public Setup() {
    initComponents();
    customComponents();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private void customComponents() {
    setTitle("Setup");
    setPatchNotesText(Browser.getVersionNotes());
    jSlider1.setValue(SettingsHandler.getDelayTime());
    jCheckBox1.setSelected(SettingsHandler.getCheckPaxWebsite());
    //More of the same type of code...
  }

  public void setPatchNotesText(final String text) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        jTextArea4.setText(text);
        jTextArea4.setCaretPosition(0);
      }
    });
  }

  private void initComponents() {

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    //Lots more component construction...

    jLabel5.setText("Setup Options");
    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
      jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
      .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addContainerGap()
        //....Begin the huge NetBeans GUI setup code. Removed for readability.
  }
}
```

And the code in the main() method...

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Initializing...");
    Browser.init();
    Email.init();
    setup = new Setup();
    while (setup.isVisible()) { // Returns true...
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    //More code...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptoms describe a classic threading issue -- a problem that occurs intermittently despite the code being unchanged. It looks like your while true might be to blame. I suggest that you instead consider:

- Make sure to start the Swing GUI on the EDT.
- Use a Swing Timer instead of the while (....) loop, and make sure that this to is called on the event thread.
- An unrelated suggestion -- you will want to give your variables names that make logical sense, that makes your code self commenting. Variable names like jLabel1, jPanel1, jTabbedPane1 will have little meaning to others who review your code (like us!), and might even confuse your future self when you want to modify or improve this program months from now.

---

**Edit** 
You post in comment:

> I want my main() Thread to pause until the GUI has been closed -- is there any way to do that between threads besides using a volatile boolean?

Yes, there are a few **much** better ways to solve this:

- Attach a WindowListener to the window that you want to listen for closing
- Or display your GUI in a modal JDialog and not a JFrame.

Comment: I want my main() Thread to pause until the GUI has been closed -- is there any way to do that between threads besides using a volatile boolean?